# Delete a file from my local changes (GIT)

Tags: git

I made some changes in my project. When i type `git log` i got the next changes:
[image]

The question is: 
How to delete from this list of changes the file `demo.js`? What command should i use?
I want to do this, because i don't want to add all files in my remote repository using the command `git add .`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command

```
git checkout -- <file-path>
```

`<file-path>` can be replaced by `.` if all files are to be removed

---

To remove all changes from `demo.js` :

```
git checkout -- demo.js
```

Comment: i tried but i got: `error: pathspec 'demo.js' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: this means that `demo.js` isn't being tracked by git (i.e, it has never been committed). So you can delete the whole file if not required else you can remove unwanted code manually and then add/commit the file. Further, if you want to keep the file locally and not commit it, you can add it to `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 1):

If you want git not to track those files, add them to `.gitignore`:

```
echo demo.js >> .gitignore
echo test.html >> .gitignore
```

You can place multiple `.gitignore` files anywhere in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an untracked file, you can delete it with your regular "file deletion command" of your shell.
In case you want to still keep the file locally on your computer, you are better of by putting it into your `.gitignore` file.